# DBMS_PROFILER - only anonymous

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to get over with DBMS_PROFILER, but I face a problem, that I can't get through.

I followed the tutorial on this page:
http://www.oracleflash.com/44/Write-fast-and-efficient-PLSQL---DBMS_PROFILER.html

and everything was fine till I did not change the user. When I run the profiler as the owner of the code, all the statistics are fine, but when I run those procedures as a different user (that of course has EXECUTE permissions) I can see only "ANONYMOUS" in profiler tables.

I found something looking around in the internet, and performed these actions:

- I granted execute permissions for user calling procedures,
- I also granted DEBUG permissions,
- I compiled procedures for DEBUG,
- I have checked that code is "INTERPRETED" and not "NATIVE",
- finally, calling user also have CREATE PROCEDURE privilege.

Nevertheless, it still doesn't work. The problem is I want to profile application, that is running code as a different user, so I cannot change that. Any ideas what should I do, and why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The doc says (in security section) that you need to have privileges to create objects that you want to monitor. I wanted to monitor package in other schemas, so at first I thought I need CREATE PROCEDURE privilege which didn't help. In fact, you need to have privileges to create specifically object you want to monitor, so you simply need to have CREATE ANY PROCEDURE for user from which you are running other shema packages.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question as Oracle 11g, in which case you are in luck.  Oracle added a new profiler package, DBMS_HPROF.  This is a hierarchical profiler, which means it can drill down into different schemas.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023)